# tornado-mysql insert not working

Tags: mysql, database, tornado

I have a problem using Tornado + Tornado-mysql.

When I **`SELECT FROM`** table, everything works as expected.
But when I try to **`INSERT INTO`** table, nothing happens. No error or anything and no data in table.

The funny thing is that when I insert a new row using other mysql clients (like *phpmyadmin*) the Auto index column, skips a number and goes +2 instead of +1.
Looks like the data has been *inserted* and then *deleted* by tornado-mysql.

Here's the code for database connection:

```
@coroutine
def TDB(query):
    conn = yield tornado_mysql.connect(host=conf.host,
                                port=conf.port,
                                user=conf.username,
                                passwd=conf.password,
                                db=conf.database,
                                charset=conf.charset,
                                cursorclass=tornado_mysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    yield cur.execute(query)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return cur._rows
```

And here's the code that sends **`insert`**/**`delete`** queries to the function above:

```
class TestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        t = await TDB('SELECT * FROM `users`') # this works fine, as expected.
        for each in t:
            print(each)
        await TDB('INSERT INTO `users` (`organization`,`username`)\
                    VALUES("PouyaCode", "pouya")') # This however doesn't work.
        self.write('hello')
```

I have the latest stable version of *tornado*, *tornado-mysql* and *mysql* itself.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: @bear not at all.

Answer (score 0):

These statements are being run in a transaction; you must either commit the transaction (by calling `conn.commit()`) before closing the connection, or run in auto-commit mode (by passing `autocommit=True` when creating the connection).